# Redirect IP with subfolder to domain (without breaking page)

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, dns

I'm having some trouble making my domain work properly. I have set up DNS on server side (digitalocean), apache .conf file in server and DNS addresses on domain (godaddy) side. Now if I enter my domain, everything seems to work fine... Until I go to any other page on that page, then it shows server IP instead of domain in browser URL bar.

site.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin name@host.com
ServerName www.site.eu
ServerAlias site.eu
DocumentRoot /var/www/site
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I also added (and then removed) this part to .htaccess, but it broke shoping cart, currency switcher and pretty much everything else (but pages had domain instead of IP in URL):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^site.eu$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://site.eu/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Any help is welcome

Comment: What's the website URL? Did you configure the DNS to actually point on your server IP or is it just some kind of redirect or iframe loading pages from the IP (most common mistake when non-DNS-savvy user configure their "DNS")?

Comment: Website URL: www.bluum.eu (maintenance page atm).
Also, pretty sure i configured DNS properly (works on wordpress pages that way, and not just redirecting (did that mistake already on the first time)).

Comment: Are your HTML links perhaps pointing to bare IP addresses......?

Answer (score 1):

You defined the IP address as your base, which is why all links are generated pointing to the IP instead of your current domain.

```
<base href="http://178.62.40.10/bluum/">
```

Change that line to your domain in your `<head>` section or remove it entirely to just let the browser choose for you.

Comment: Couldn't find anything like that in <head> section, so I used grep to find all files including server IP... Found 2 files (both config.php), 6 lines in total. Changed all to domain instead of IP/bluum and it broke the page (500 Internal Server Error).
Lines in 1st Config.php: "define ('HTTP_SERVER..." and HTTPS,
Lines in 2nd Config.php: "define ('HTTP_SERVER..." and HTTPS, and "define HTTP_CATALOG..." and HTTPS.
First try broke the page so changed only SERVER lines to domain and still broke it.

Comment: Well, I'm an idiot... And appparently I'll still be an idiot after this... Found "<base href="<?php echo $base; ?>" />" and now I'm having trouble finding where it gets that $base from.

Comment: It seems like you're using OpenCart - I've never used that software before but `$base` is set in the header.php controller file from what I could find. It gets the values from the config, `config_url` and `config_ssl` to be exact. See the [source code art GitHub](https://github.com/opencart/opencart/blob/master/upload/catalog/controller/common/header.php).

Comment: Got those lines related to $base:
  if (isset($this->request->server['HTTPS']) && (($this->request->server['HTTPS'] == 'on') || ($this->request->server['HTTPS'] == '1'))) {
   $this->data['base'] = HTTPS_SERVER;
  } else {
   $this->data['base'] = HTTP_SERVER;
  }

I also noticed that not all pages break. Only pages that use /pagename break, while pages that use route=page work properly.
(EDIT: Still new to this site... How to put stuff into code?)